# gcloud node datastore - how to filter multiple entities keys in a single transaction?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a list of keys for entites I want to read.
I can't find a way to read them in a single transaction

Is there a way to do something like this -

```
var query = datastore.createQuery('Task').filter('someProp', 'in', ['val1', 'val2'])
```

If someone knows about a specific solution for filtering according to multiple keys it will also work for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Datastore doesn't support OR operator and you need to perform separate queries per each value and combine and distinct the results on your end.

There is the [Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/) whole allows you to build documents and have more complex query for them but it is not avaliable for nodejs.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872654/is-there-or-operator-in-gql)

Comment: This only works for array type properties. It will return entities where the array someProp contains a value that equals val1 or val2. I trying to find entities where a property equals one of an array of possible values, but the property itself is a single field, like id.

Comment: @Gyro you are right (it been a long time since I dealt with the Datastore), see new answer

Comment: You can only query for entities inside the same entity group (ancestor query)  inside a transaction.